# Using wsimport from windows - url = http://www.webservicex.net/geoipservice.asmx?WSDL

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, wsimport

I get this error when I used the URL

```
http://www.webservicex.net/geoipservice.asmx?WSDL
```

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_18\bin>wsimport **<URL>**
parsing WSDL...

[WARNING] Ignoring SOAP port "GeoIPServiceSoap12": it uses non-standard SOAP 1.2
 binding.
You must specify the "-extension" option to use this binding.
  line 197 of **<URL>**

[WARNING] ignoring port "GeoIPServiceHttpGet": no SOAP address specified. try ru
nning wsimport with -extension switch.
  line 200 of **<URL>**

[WARNING] ignoring port "GeoIPServiceHttpPost": no SOAP address specified. try r
unning wsimport with -extension switch.
  line 203 of **<URL>**
generating code...

**[ERROR] .\net\webservicex\GeoIP.java (The system cannot find the path specified)**

C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_18\bin>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error suggests the compiler needs GeoIP.java in order to progress - which should (technically) be given by your WSDL. I had this error, and it was because I did not have permissions to write to the directory (in this case, you're writing to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_18\bin` - simple test would just be to try and run `mkdir TEST` in this directory) so GeoIP (for example) could not be written.

Specify a directory using the `-d` switch or change your working directory to one where you have permissions.

Answer (score 3):

This error is coming because of permission issue.

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin> mkdir test
```

Access is denied.

Try using another directory to place generated files.

```
wsimport [options] < WSDL_URL > -d <directory>
```

specifies where to place generated output files

E:\sei is the directory, i am using to place output class files.

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin> wsimport -d E:\sei http://www.webservicex.net/geoipservice.asmx?wsdl
```

Answer (score 1):

In case `http://www.webservicex.net/geoipservice.asmx?WSDL` is not responding, use `http://wsgeoip.lavasoft.com/ipservice.asmx?WSDL` instead.